# Is it possible to use CDK Virtual Scroll Viewport with CDK A11y - ActiveDescendantKeyManager?

Tags: angular, accessibility, angular-cdk, virtualscroll

I am using `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>` with a fixed items size for virtual scrolling.

Furthermore I use `ActiveDescendantKeyManager` provided by CDK A11y to move with the arrow keys inside the viewport.

When I try to use both of them I have the following issue:

Since virtual scroll only loads partial information and loads more when you scroll (recycling the view), `ActiveDescendantKeyManager` only get the indexes of the current items loaded by the `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>`. As I load more, the indexes repeats themselves, since the virtual scroll adds and deletes items, `keyManager` just acts weird, since I want the indexes to be in order (if I have 5000 items I want the indexes to be in order, not only from 1-24 and each time I scroll they repeat).
[Here is an example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmawwx)

My question is: Is there any way to work with both of them? since what I am trying  to do is to move with the arrow keys to the following scroll index.

Comment: I have a very similar problem (and interestingly made a very similar-looking StackBlitz!) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55696084/indexing-or-selecting-all-viewchildren-within-a-cdk-virtual-scroller Hopefully we can find a solution to this, it's kind of broken!